# What criteria should be considered when testing report generation

Tags: manual-testing, test-data

My web application generates a lot of reports in formats like excel sheet, Csv(comma-separated values), fixed width columns, pdf format, html reports etc based on the parameters I select. There is a lot of data in the reports.

Are there any essential criteria for testing report generation that I may not have considered.

I know to test these things:

- Data is correct
- Filters are used
- Output format is correct

What else is there?

Comment: Who are the targetted end users / consumers of these reports?

Comment: Have you tried manipulating the data used to generate the reports? You could simplify it so that the output for each report is completely predictable, yet covers all the test cases.

Comment: So you are testing the reports themselves?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to verify following things:

1. Verify the downloaded report is in correct format for example if you select pdf option then pdf should get downloaded and not html or other
2. Verify the name of downloaded file is as expected, many a times file has some naming conventions which are followed
3. Verify the header and footers if any
4. Verify the calculations mentioned in report are correct
5. Verify images or graphs mentioned in report are correct with appropriate units
6. Verify copy paste or editing report is allowed or not - In case report has read only access
7. Verify color of legend in report is appropriate if any
8. Verify name of sheets are appropriate if there are multiple sheets
9. Verify date time zone country etc are correct
10. Verify email ids mentioned in reports are correct if any
11. Verify same report is shown if downloaded multiple times (there was time I faced issue every time we download report, it used to show different report)

Answer (score 3):

While testing reports we need to take the following points into consideration -

1. Input data validations eg. date ranges
2. Format of the report
3. Check if there are any calculations like total, max or min values
4. Units are displayed correctly eg. currency
5. Data is displayed correctly based on filters
6. Page navigation and number of rows displayed per page
7. Any links on reports work correctly
8. Time taken by the report to load
9. Report shows same data in different formats
10. No duplicate records