# Reports verification

Tags: automated-testing, gui

Currently I have a task to validate set of reports which is developed by using the logianalysis tool.

Can anyone let me the idea to validate the reports through an interface level as well as data level.

Is there is any automation tool is available in the market to make this task easier.

Comment: This is similar in subject and level of detail to http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/16820/test-ideas-for-testing-reports, which was closed for being too broad.

Comment: It seems to be the not similar question. I just need information about the key areas not need detailed test scenarios etc..

Comment: Just because it's not similar in subject matter doesn't mean it's not similar in type. This type of question is generally too broad for this site. If you have selected a tool, asking "how do I use tool X to do task Y" is still not a good question, unless your question is "I'm using tool X to perform task Y by doing Z, and now I am running into problem P, how do I solve problem P?"

Comment: Cronax good feedback I will agree with your comment